# How to create a multi select checkbox list in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vbscript, excel-2010

i am trying to implement a multi-select dropdown list in excel, refer below for the image

[image]

As you can see, it is part implemented, but as it is not intuitive, I would like to have a checkbox in place of the dropdown where the 3 options - APR, LEASE and CASH exists. Thanks in advance to anybody who can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using in-cell dropdown use an Active-X List Box, set MultiSelect to fmMultiSelectMulti and ListStyle to fmListStyleOption.